# Can I migrate processes between fat containers?

Tags: docker, containers

I recently began getting into Docker and containers. Up to now, I understand that the philosophy behind containers is to run one process per container so we end up with applications which can be run easily and consistently regardless of the environment. Also, that containers are intrinsically connected to it's image, so if you want to save the changes to a container you need to commit and create a new image.

But let's say I want to run multiple processes inside a single container, AKA a fat container. I know it can be done and things like "Supervisord" and "Baseimage-docker" can help manage processes within fat containers.

**Now we get to my question**: Is there a way to have a fat container running, save the run state of a single process and migrate said process to another container?

I've looked online but I haven't really found anyone that has said that this is possible. So I'm turning to you guys in case one of you have thought about this problem or maybe I've missed something along the way.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure if the question might be opinion based. but here is what i think you might be able to do, lets say you have a web application like a Django application that uses Redis within the same container, which will be considered as a fat container and you need to migrate redis to be a standalone service within its own container then you have to do the following:

1- Prepare a docker image that has Redis installed you might go with your own image or use the official redis docker image.

2- Copy the configuration that is being used with redis from the fat container so you can mount it later inside the new redis container

3- Change the Django application settings and make it point to that new redis container

4- Remove redis service and its configuration from the fat container or maybe build a new image.

and thats it, now you should start the redis container and restart the django application container to take effect or start a new one if you modified the fat image.

Answer (score 0):

There's the famous [Quake demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mL9AFkJJAq0&feature=youtu.be&t=22m14s) and the ability to migrate the state of an entire container with CRIU. That's probably the closest I've seen to what you're talking about. More here: https://criu.org/Docker

As far as a "single" process inside a container, maybe just migrate the entire container and kill the processes you want moved?

I would say the more common pattern in the Docker community is single process containers that are freely killed/updated/etc.